# Visual basic changing value based on value

Tags: vba

Basically I have 10 integers named:

```
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,i10
```

Now I have a calculation, and whenever it returns a value between 1-10, then it must increase the according integer by 1.

I know that I can do this with case or 10 ifs, but is there a way to generate the variable name, what I want to change. Pseudocode:

```
value = x // a value is being returned
(i+x)++;  // increase the according variable by one
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply create an array and, based upon the value being returned, increment the value in the array at the given index?

For example:

```
Dim myArray(1 To 10) As Integer
value = x                          'a value is being returned
myArray(x) = myArray(x) + 1        'increment value in array
```

Comment: This is nice, but is there a oneliner that allows me initialize all 10 values to `2` ? or I must do `myArray(1) = 2`  ten times?

Comment: or... myArray = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]   (but you have to use a variant array for this)

Comment: @enderland pretty much covered it. Those are the options